# External js is loading in react component only after refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, external-js

My Component.

```
import useScript from "./useScript";
function MyComponent(): JSX.Element {
useScript("https://dev-kpaymentgateway.kasikornbank.com/ui/v2/kinlinepayment.min.js", "pkey_test_20184OBD88Yvl6uplpR0kY0ZTpVz46h1Tdqyj");
return (
    <div className={greyContainer}>
        <div className={gridContainer}>

            <p id="error-summary">
                Oops something went wrong, please try again.
            </p>

            <div className="flied">
                <label className="label"> name</label>

                <div id="name"></div>
                <label> Name is invalid.</label>
            </div>

            <div className="flied">
                <label className=" label">Number</label>

                <div id="number"></div>
                <label>Number is invalid.</label>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div style={{textAlign: "right", marginBottom: 10, marginTop: 30}}>
            <form method="POST" action="https://httpbin.org/post">
                <button type="submit" className="pay-button">Pay now</button>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
);
}
```

I load script using `react hook`. This script is supposed to add some field in component above.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

const useScript = (url, dataKey) => {
useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src = url;
    script["data-key"] = dataKey;
    script["data-lang"] = "en";
    script["data-write-log"] = true;
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);

    return () => { document.body.removeChild(script);};
    }, [url]);
  };

  export default useScript;
```

My script is loading but only after refresh the page where I have used the component `MyComponent`. I am using `react-router5` for navigation.

Can anybody explain why it is happening and how to overcome it.

Comment: after every refresh it will load that file , why is that a problem /

Comment: Scenario demand the script to be loaded without refresh

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-breeze-pehw0  you are not giving me complete code , may be your'e importing mycomponent somewhere esle, cuz in codesandbox i can only refresh the page to load the script, and there is no button according to your component,that allows me to fetch that **kinline**  without page refresh.

Comment: alos this thing is not secure https://ibb.co/HqBfbsw

Comment: I have edited. It will run now

Answer (score 1):

My best guess is that the [kinlinepayment.min.js](https://dev-kpaymentgateway.kasikornbank.com/ui/v2/kinlinepayment.min.js) script was executed just fine. But it registers an event listener for an event that already happened and will not happen again:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",e())
```

You could try to dispatch that event (and all backup events if you need to support old browsers) in your useEffect:

```
...
document.body.appendChild(script);

document.dispatchEvent(new Event('DOMContentLoaded')))

return ...
```

Comment: sir, I have add the line as you have said.
document.dispatchEvent(new Event('DOMContentLoaded')))

But nothing happend.

Comment: I have put this line in setInterval also but it did not worked

Comment: oh well, it looks like it will be a more complex problem, so you might need to ask for support directly in kasikornbank.com, how to use their service correctly

Comment: I have loaded the script  kinlinepayment.min.js.  But I have not been able to use
KInlineCheckout object. Can you give any suggestion